# Azure "security rules" for tor-middle node

Tags: middle, firewall

I trying to set-up a tor middle relay on Azure.

I've an Ubuntu instance, tor is all installed and has bootstrapped fine, but it won't form a circuit and the ORPort is unreachable.

I assume this is a firewall issue, and digging around on portal.azure.com I found the instances security rules.

Has anyone got a good how-to for setting the MS Azure rules up? failing that what ports do I need open (is it just the ORPort and 9050?)

Thanks

Comment: You need to at least open your ORPort, and if you are mirroring the directory, you will need to open your DirPort as well. You can find which ports are being used in the torrc config file.

Comment: It turns out it wasn't a firewall issues, but my set-up.